# How to check if a child table contains a particular record

Tags: c#, sql, linq, parent-child, contains

I have a Member object objMember.  I got it from LINQ

```
  Dim objMember = (From m In db.Members
      Where m.LoginName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
      Select m).First
```

A Member has SignUps - a many-to-many table that links a MemberID and a ClassID

I have a ClassID - an integer

It seems that I should be able to query objMember.SignUps, and see if it has one for objMember.MemberID + ClassID.  And it seems I should not have to query the DB again to get this answer.  When I break my code and inspect objMember.SignUps, I see that it seems to have them in memory.

I have tried this, but it always returns False.

```
 Dim su As New SignUp
 su.ClassID = ClassID
 su.MemberID = objMember.MemberID
 If objMember.SignUps.Contains(su) Then
```

What is the right way to check objMember.SignUps to see if it has a particular SignUp record?

Comment: Which "LINQ" are you referring to? LINQ to SharePoint?

Comment: I didn't think it would matter for the syntax, but it's LINQ to SQL in an ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the load options of the query before you make it:

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Member>(m => m.SignUps);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

otherwise the lazy loading of the query won't load the child options. Do this for every child object you want to load with the main query.

The other alternative is to do an explicit `join` on the two tables in your query. This will pull back the data you require.

Also your test:

```
If objMember.SignUps.Contains(su) Then
```

is wrong. This is checking if the **new** object you have created is in the list - which it won't be. You need to use the `Any` method:

```
If objMember.SignUps.Any(s => s.ClassID == ClassID && s.MemberID == objMember.MemberID) Then
```

This will check if any object with these properties exists in the collection.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!  objMember.Signups.Any.  Being new at this, I didn't think of querying the actual collection that I already had in memory.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because `Contains` will do an object comparison to see if `objMember.Signups` has `su`, this will always return false.

You can either use an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of contains which will let you specify the ClassID and MemberID, or use another LINQ expression, such as

```
From s in signups
Where s.ClassID == ... && s.UserID == ...
```

Comment: Thanks too for clarifying why the way I was using Contains didn't work.